# ActiveMQ fails to deliver to topic subscriber

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

My web app communicates to my mobile app via ActiveMQ durable topics via MQTT (Paho). To deliver messages to the mobile device a separate topic is created for every mobile user. All messages from mobile devices are directed to a single topic.

This configuration seem to work fine, but every once a while something strange happens, the messages are not delivered to a device. Here is what's happening.

- The user specific topic for messages sent to the device is dynamically created and looks fine in the console.
- The messages sent to the topic seem to be enqueued fine - the count in the console is incremented
- The client seems to be active - at least the console shows that the topic has an active subscriber
- No messages are delivered to the client - The dequeued counter is stuck at 0
- while the topic for this particular user is not working, other topics for other users work fine - messages are delivered as expected
- Deleting topic for the user from the console and having it recreated does not work. The topic disappears from the console and reappears after it is recreated with the same counters it had before deleting. The message delivery still does not work
- Restarting the broker fixes the problem

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you consistently using the same client ID on your subscribers or allowing this to be auto-generated?

Comment: @ErikWilliams I am. But I never have more than one client subscribed - at least not intentionally

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having multiple clients subscribed to the same topic, but with durable topics, if you do not reconnect with the same client ID you will not get any messages from that durable topic. So be sure that whatever client is connected and not getting messages has the same client ID as the original subscriber that created the durable topic subscription.

Comment: For now I have clientID hardcoded in the client. My understanding is that in this situation an attempt to subscribe again with the same clientID will cause an exception, but I do not see anything in the logs. Besides I am pretty sure that I close the client before I try to start it again. So how can I have 2 connections from the same client? Unless ActiveMQ for some reason thinks that the connection from the first client is still around even though I closed it

Comment: You are correct. What I meant was, that durable topic messages are associated with a client ID.  So, if that particular client disconnects, the durable topic subscription for that client ID remains so that no publications are missed while the client is disconnected.  If you reconnect with that same Client ID you should be getting the messages.

Comment: Yep, that's what I expected, but for some reason I am not getting anything - that's the problem

Comment: One thing I overlooked was you were looking at the topic dequeue count. Make sure you are looking at the subscriber dequeue count. I don't know the reasoning, but with durable topics you won't see the dequeue count go up on the topic its self, only on the durable subscription

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63817/discussion-between-mfeingold-and-erik-williams).